# Coworker is not taking the initiative and I am picking up the slack

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, ethics

My coworker (I will call him Fred) and I have been working in the office with our supervisor working remotely. We are in IT so aside from email responses we have various tasks that need to be tended to. You could probably get away with ignoring lots of these small tasks but eventually they would pile up until someone would need to do something about them or take notice. I have been training / mentoring Fred for the last 6 months who came on the job with very little IT experience. Nepotism was at work here because my coworker is my supervisors friends friend. Long story. Anyways I have worked this job alone for over a year before Fred started.

I have always been a business first then kick-back later person. Fred is entirely the opposite. Fred has basically told me on many occasions to just stop giving effort. Fred rarely if ever looks up from his phone so I am fielding most of the emails and calls. I let my supervisor know about this on multiple occasions and his answer is always that I should just hold off responding to emails for a while and see if my coworker takes them. I almost feel that I am being scolded for bringing the matter up. I feel guilty when I see a task and I have to wait for Fred to notice 10 minutes later or never sometimes only for him to ask me what he is supposed to do because he does not want to put forth the effort to learn himself. The small tasks that Fred picks are never completed right and I am not the kind of person to tell because he is always careless with mistakes. My supervisor is not paying attention or observant.

Seriously stressed out here. We have no HR person presently at the company. I do not want to quit because it is a decent job while I look for another one which I am doing. Fred seems very comfortable talking about Acid and other drugs at the workplace with me. I am against drugs dont ask dont tell. I told him about some insomnia I am having and he says I should smoke grass. No thanks.

Comment: "I do not want to quit ... while I look for another [job] which I am doing" -- Seems like you answered your own question. Otherwise, I am not sure what the _question_ is here, exactly. Seems like you just made a post regarding your current situation which you do not like. Nothing we can answer about that.

Comment: The pivotal detail is that Fred was hired in a favor transaction between the manager and another party. The degree of "protection" this gives to Fred depends on the status of the other party and their relationship to the manager. How to proceed depends on that, unfortunately. In the worst case, the realistic option may be "containment", by assigning Fred some harmless tasks. In the best case, the manager can help motivate Fred to take OP's instruction more seriously.

Answer (score 4):

"Take this up immediately, and privately, with your manager."  End of story.

This is your manager's **fundamental** job responsibility.  If there is any "issue" among any of his/her "direct reports," that "issue" is *theirs* to resolve.  Your responsibility is to raise it to them – privately.  Do not attempt direct communication with your co-worker to address the matter "out of band." Strictly follow the HR protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds almost as if you and Fred may have the exact same job responsibilities. If so then maybe try splitting the responsibilities. Like let Fred be in charge of emails. Audit the emails he sends out and provide mentorship but let him be in charge of them whilst you're in charge of other things. If Fred is giving ownership of something he might become more emotionally invested in it.

Like it seems like right now that if shit hits the fan you'll take the heat and shield Fred from it. So give him more responsibility and make him more of a stakeholder than it sounds like he currently is.